# Is it possible to set a debug point in FreeMarker template file?

Tags: eclipse, freemarker

I have a lot of coding in FreeMarker template files for view layer in my app.

I was wondering if I can set a debug point with Eclipse. Is there any good plugin that I can use to debug FreeMarker template files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot. A template file is a plain text file that the template engine reads into memory and then uses to produce a document that it writes to the response. It's not actually executable code. You can put a breakpoint in the template engine code and follow along what it replaces and how.

Answer (score 3):

FreeMarker has a debugging API, although it has stuck in experimental state eons ago, mostly because nobody has taken the effort to write a front-end for it (like an Eclipse plugin). Except, I know they have planned to support it under some of the next LifeRay IDE versions. As far as I know they managed with break points, but there's no support for stepping in the FreeMarker API for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and answering it right now doesn't make sense, but maybe it helps to all those people who often visit this page to find whether there is a way to debug freemarker or not.

As in the earlier answer it was stated that there is an Official API for the debugging, so just to add a little more into it for beginners.

Please refer to this official API and check **freemarker.debug** package [*as official description says* - **Debugging API; experimental status, might change! This is to support debugging in IDE-s.**], it is surely to help. 
[FreeMarker 2.3.29](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/index.html)